# HIVE or PIG as an alternative for Amazon Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, apache-pig, amazon-redshift

We are using Amazon Redshift to extract data from our S3 bucket. We want to reduce the cost by replacing Redshift with HIVE or PIG.

Can we use HIVE or PIG to extract data from an Amazon S3 bucket?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Don't ask can it be done. Instead say "I've tried extracting the data using HIVE but it fails at this point.... What am I doing wrong". Your current question is a candidate for a google search, not a StackOverflow question.

Comment: Can you provide more details of your use-case? How much data do you have? Do you run queries throughout the day, or just in a daily batch? What is your current cost of Redshift?

Answer (score 3):

Amazon Elastic MapReduce can be used to deploy an Apache Hadoop cluster, including Hive and Pig.

This cluster can access data in S3, perform ETL operations and save your data back in Amazon S3. However, it is a **rather complex system to use** and would also incur charges (especially if you keep it running all day).

If you are concerned about the cost of Amazon Redshift, some options are:

- Use a smaller cluster (pricing is per-node)
- Turn off Redshift at night. Take a snapshot first, then restore the snapshot the next morning.
- Purchase a Reserved Instance for Redshift to lower the price

Comment: Thank you Jhon for you answer. Let me get back with more stats about this problem